# Is there a way to compile C++ code inside from c++

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to coding overall, and I am making a basic compiler for a language I'm making which I will convert to C++ to be compiled into binary via third party compiler. Any way I can do this inside of C++ instead of running a script?

Thanks,

Comment: A C++ program can run another process, such as a C++ compiler, if that's what you are asking. See e.g. [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to compile C++ code inside from c++

No, there is no standard function that would compile C++. Yes, it is possible to write a C++ compiler in C++. Some C++ compilers are in fact written (in large parts) in C++.

It can however be quite a bit of work to write your own C++ compiler. I recommend considering to use an existing compiler. Note that if you wish to bundle someone else's with your program, you need to carefully understand the license of that compiler and its implications.